# How to make the last array key's data move to the first array key? the second last array key's data move to second array key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

Refer to the question's title, I just want to know how to change it?
for example, my array data is like this

```
Array(
      [0] => Array(
                  [data] => 'blahblah',
                  [time] => '',
             )
      [1] => Array(
                  [data] => 'abc',
                  [time] => '',
             )
      [2] => Array(
                  [data] => '123',
                  [time] => '',
             )
      [3] => Array(
                  [data] => '456',
                  [time] => '',
             )
      [4] => Array(
                  [data] => '789',
                  [time] => '',
             )
      [5] => Array(
                  [data] => '000',
                  [time] => '',
             )
      [6] => Array(
                  [data] => '111',
                  [time] => '',
             )
)
```

how I can move the key[6] array data to key[0]? the key[0] data will move to key[6] at the same time. key[5]data <=> key[1]data, key[4]data <=> key[2]data. Thanks in advance. Programming language: php

Comment: Welcome. Can you please post your own efforts for solving this? What have you tried so far that doesn't work? Do you basically want to _reverse_ an _array_?

Comment: So you basically want to reverse the array?

Comment: [array_reverse()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) will work

Comment: @kerbholz I already tried array_reverse. The array_reverse() reverses all data including the keys. I want the key's data array reversed only no including keys reverse.

Comment: In short you want to keep keys as it is right?

Comment: @Rahul Yes. Any solutions?

Comment: Yes check my answer.

Comment: A simple foreach loop with key and value would have done it.

Answer (score 2):

You pass true as second parameter,

```
$arr = array_reverse($arr,true);
print_r($arr);
```

[array_reverse](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) — Return an array with elements in reverse order

> **Note:-**
>   **preserve_keys**
>   If set to **TRUE** numeric keys are preserved. Non-numeric keys are not affected by this setting and will always be
>   preserved.

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/1fhfp)

**Output:-**

```
Array
(
    [6] => Array
        (
            [data] => 111
            [time] => 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [data] => 000
            [time] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [data] => 789
            [time] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [data] => 456
            [time] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [data] => 123
            [time] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [data] => abc
            [time] => 
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [data] => blahblah
            [time] => 
        )

)
```